# Game Center in Enterprise iOS Apps?

Tags: ios, game-center, in-house-distribution

Is it possible to have Game Center leaderboards or achievements in an in house distributed enterprise app? The enterprise program doesn't seem to give you access to iTunes Connect, but I can't see any reason to not allow this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no.

Game Center data is intended to be globally visible.
Enterprise Program apps are not.

Answer (score 0):

You are still able to test GameCenter on an Enterprise Account. It will be running in SandBox mode as in Development though.